# Dropdown to change tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage and refresh page

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

I'm looking for a way to change dynamically the tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage of tx_news in FE.  I would like the user to set the number of items in FE and the news will automatically refresh.

Can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work out like this

**1st: adopt the template**

This will add a select with the options

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="">default</option>
    <option value="{f:uri.action(action:'list',addQueryString:1,additionalParams:{count:2})}">2</option>
    <option value="{f:uri.action(action:'list',addQueryString:1,additionalParams:{count:5})}">5</option>
    <option value="{f:uri.action(action:'list',addQueryString:1,additionalParams:{count:10})}">10</option>
    <option value="{f:uri.action(action:'list',addQueryString:1,additionalParams:{count:20})}">20</option>
</select>
```

what is currently missing is a check on {settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage} and add the `selected` attribute.

**2nd: add some TS**

```
[globalVar = GP:count = 2]
plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage = 2
config.linkVars = count
[END]

[globalVar = GP:count = 5]
plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage = 5
config.linkVars = count
[END]

[globalVar = GP:count = 10]
plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage = 10
config.linkVars = count
[END]
```